# Overiding __mul__ in two dimensional vector class to preserve commutivity

Tags: python

I have defined the following class:

```
class Point(object):

    def __repr__(self):
        return "("+str(self.x)+","+str(self.y)+")"

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, point):
        return Point(self.x+point.x,self.y+point.y)

    def __sub__(self, point):
        return Point(self.x-point.x,self.y-point.y)

    def __mul__(self, num):
         return Point(num*self.x,num*self.y)

    def length(self):
        return (self.x**2 + self.y**2)**.5
```

And the following code works:

```
x = Point(1,2)
y = Point(1,3)
print x+y
print (y+x)
print (x-y)
print (y-x)
print y*3
```

with output:

```
(2,5)
(2,5)
(0,-1)
(0,1)
(3,9)
```

But this does not:

```
print 3*y
```

It gives the following error:

```
----> 1 print 3*y
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Point'
```

Which is because the point class is being fed into the int **mul** function, I'm assuming. How can I keep the definition of point contained in the Point class and still have 3*y return the same as y*3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
3 * y
```

We have an `int` instance on the left side, and a `Point` instance on the right.  `Point` is not a subclass of `int`.  In this situation, `int.__mul__` class gets the first chance at this operation, and `Point.__mul__` gets no say in the matter.

You'll have to implement `Point.__rmul__` on your class to handle the case.

Answer (score 3):

Based on wim's answer, here's a tested and working implementation:

```
class Point(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "(" + str(self.x) + "," + str(self.y) + ")"

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, point):
        return Point(self.x + point.x, self.y + point.y)

    def __sub__(self, point):
        return Point(self.x - point.x, self.y - point.y)

    def __mul__(self, num):
        return Point(num * self.x, num * self.y)

    def __rmul__(self, num):
        return self.__mul__(num)

    def length(self):
        return self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2


x = Point(1, 2)
y = Point(1, 3)

print(x + y)
print(y + x)
print(x - y)
print(y - x)
print(y * 3)
print(3 * y)
```

**Output**

```
(2,5)
(2,5)
(0,-1)
(0,1)
(3,9)
(3,9)
```

The last two outputs being equal demonstrates commutativity of the operation.