# Overload binary operators to support right application

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a class `A` that supports both multiplication between two instances of `A` and scalar multiplication.

I currently have the following implementation for the `__mul__` method:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, value: float):
        self.value = value

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if type(other) == A:
            return A(self.value * other.value)
        elif type(other) == float:
            return A(other * self.value)
        else:
            raise
```

This allows to perform multiplication `x * y` where `x` is an instance of `A` and `y` is an intance of `A` or `float`. However if `x` is a `float` and `y` in an `A` then a  `TypeError` is raised.

Is there a way to overload this case as well? If it matters, I would like the same behaviour regardless of whether the instance of `A` is the left or right operand.

Comment: `__rmul__` should work

Comment: See [_Overiding `__mul__` in two dimensional vector class to preserve commutivity_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41512646/674039)

Comment: better use `isinstance` than `type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `__rmul__`:

```py
class A:
    ...
    __rmul__ = __mul__
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZFNCsIwEIVx21MMuElFi38LKXTRk4SiExqIbUlSoZfwAm660UN5GtOkaYPi7DLv5Zu8zOPVdLqsq75_tpptTu_F_SwKpSBPIzB1QQaU8oprSolCwdZwK0SLKTBRFzp2rqEGMbEaZM4TBYRrKyZArUuUwc1lI3mlie4aJE6LJ40zCPqQZf5hviTqVlaQk2D-yo1wp5mF4pdmU_whWpeBzeSQpfDrWsEV2g6l0sY1_zAGjyIXkeTkkOyOsYHuk23soaNoWkYYLV50axm347f0AQ)